# How to expand associated Legendre polynomials into Chebyshev polynomials.

Tags: fourier-transform, legendre-polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

I am trying to expand Associated Legendre polynomials of order m=2 into Chebyshev polynomials, shown as:
$$P^{2}_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}T_{k}(x), $$
where $P^{2}_{n}$ is Associated Legendre polynomials of order m=2, $T_{k}$ is Chebyshev polynomials, and $a_{k}$ are unknown coefficients.

As the Orthogonality of Chebyshev polynomial is
$$\int_{-1}^{1}T_{j}(x)T_{k}(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\delta_{jk},\quad j^{2}+k^{2}\neq0,$$
so
$$a_{k}(n,k)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}P^{2}_{n}(x)T_{k}(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx.$$
But i do not how to do this integral analytically.

I found a [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4222642/integral-of-legendre-and-chebyshev-polynomials) on how to expend Legendre polynomials into Chebyshev polynomials using the generation function. Still, I do not know how to generalize it to the Associated Legendre polynomials.

Can anyone help? Many thanks!

Comment: **Why not the same way?** Use $\sum_{n=2}^\infty P_n''(x)t^{n-2}=3(1-2xt+t^2)^{-5/2}$ obtained by taking $\partial^2/\partial x^2$ of the generating function for $P_n(x)$, the definition $P_n^2(x)=(1-x^2)P_n''(x)$, and the power series for $(1-z)^{-5/2}$, to get $\sum_{n=2}^\infty P_n^2(\cos\theta)t^{n-2}$ as a power series in $t$ whose coefficients are represented *explicitly* as finite trigonometric sums.

Comment: thanks for answering, I agree we can get $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}=p^{\prime\prime}_{n}(cos)t^{n−2}$, but how to deal with the prefactor $(1−^2)=\sin^{2}\theta$, how to cooperate this prefactor into the expansion of $(1−)^{−5/2}$?

Comment: i mean how to expand the prefactor $(1-x^2)=\sin^{2}\theta$ into the $\cos{k}\theta$ series.

Comment: $\sin^2\theta=(1-\cos2\theta)/2$ and product-to-sum for $\cos A\cos B$ (or write everything in terms of $e^{i\theta}$).