# Distributional Fourier Transform of $P_{n}(\cos x)$

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory, dirac-delta, legendre-polynomials

Consider the following set of Fourier transforms (understood as distributions since formally these are divergent):
$$
D_{n}(y) := \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P_{n}(\cos x) e^{i x y} dx
$$
where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x>0$, and $P_{n}$ are Legendre Polynomials.

Does there exist a close form expression for $D_{n}$ for general $n$?

One ingredient needed is the representation
$$
\delta(y)= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ixy} dy
$$
of the delta function. With this, since $P_0(\cos x) = 1$ and $P_1(\cos x) = \cos x$ and $P_2(\cos x) = \frac{1}{2}( 3 \cos^2 x - 1 )$, its easily shown that $D_0(y) = \delta(y)$ and $D_{1}(y)= \frac{1}{2} \delta(y - 1) +  \frac{1}{2} \delta(y + 1)$ as well as $D_{2}(y) = \frac{1}{4} \delta(y) + \frac{3}{8} \delta(y - 2) +\frac{3}{8} \delta(y + 2)$.

Can one generalize this more simply?

Comment: One can use the recursion formula for the Legendre polynomials.

Comment: In formula (2.3) of [this compendium of formulas](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01116888/document), there is a similar computation using the Rodrigues formulas. I am **not sure** this can help, but that's the best I can do.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Unfortunately, in that reference, they are taking the finite Fourier transform $\int_a^b P_n(x) e^{ix\lambda }\,dx$ and not $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P_n(\cos(x)) e^{ix\lambda }\,dx$

Comment: @MarkViola: Yeah, that's unfortunate. But the formula of Rodrigues still stands. Maybe the approach generalises, I don't know. I haven't tried.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I had a quick look; it doesn't look tractable.   The recursion formula is the best I could do given limited time.

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent to finding the Fourier expansion of $P_n(\cos x)$ (done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4223032) by myself): $$P_n(\cos x)=\sum_{k=0}^n b_k b_{n-k}e^{i(n-2k)x},$$ where $b_n=2^{-2n}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$.

Comment: This answer should be accepted.