# Solution of $\int_0^{\infty}p\,dp \int_0^{\pi} d \theta\,\frac{\cos n \theta}{(p^2+k^2-2pk\cos\theta)^{1/2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, special-functions

How can I solve this integral

> \begin{equation} \int_0^{\infty}p dp \int_0^{\pi} d \theta \frac{\cos n \theta}{(p^2+k^2-2pk\cos\theta)^{1/2}} \end{equation}
>
> where $k>0$ and $n=2,3,4,\cdots$.

---

**What I have done:**

First of all, I have used Laplace expansion in spherical coordinates:
\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|} =\sum_{\ell =0}^{\infty} \frac{r_<^{\ell}}{r_{>}^{\ell+1}}P_{\ell}(\cos\gamma), \quad \text{where} \ \cos\gamma = \cos\theta \cos\theta' + \sin\theta \sin\theta' \cos(\phi-\phi')
\end{equation}
So we can assume that $\mathbf{k} = (k,0,0)$ and $\mathbf{p} = (p,\theta,0)$ in spherical coordinates. And we get:
\begin{equation*}
        \frac{1}{(p^2 + k^2 - 2pk \cos\theta)^{1/2}} = \sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty} \frac{r_<^{\ell}}{r_{>}^{\ell + 1}} P_{\ell}(\cos\theta)
\end{equation*}
Then the integral becomes:

\begin{align}
        &\int_0^{\infty} p\ \mathrm{d}{p} \int_0^{\pi} \ \mathrm{d}{\theta} \frac{\cos n \theta}{(p^2 + k^2 - 2pk \cos\theta)^{1/2}} \\[.2cm]
        ={}& \sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty} \left( \int_0^{k}\frac{p^{\ell}}{k^{\ell+1}}\cdot  p  \ \mathrm{d}{p} + \int_k^{\infty}\frac{k^{\ell}}{p^{\ell + 1}}\cdot p\ \mathrm{d}p\right)\left(\int_0^{\pi}\cos(n\theta) P_{\ell}(\cos\theta)\ \mathrm{d}{\theta}\right)\\[.2cm]
={}&k\cdot\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\frac{2\ell+1}{(\ell+2)(\ell-1)}\left(\int_0^{\pi}\cos(n\theta) P_{\ell}(\cos\theta)\ \mathrm{d}{\theta}\right)
\end{align}

I have used the Fourier expansion of Legendre polynomials which can be derived from the generating function.

> [You can see it from my
> answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4222642/integral-of-legendre-and-chebyshev-polynomials/4651792#4651792),

\begin{equation}
P_{n}(\cos\theta) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!} \frac{(2n-2k-1)!!}{(2n-2k)!!} \cos[(n-2k)\theta]
\end{equation}
We set the coefficient as $a_{nk}$:
\begin{equation}
a_{nk} = \frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!} \frac{(2n-2k-1)!!}{(2n-2k)!!}
\end{equation}
Thus, the integral over angles can be transformed into
\begin{align}
        \int_0^{\pi}\cos(n\theta) P_{\ell}(\cos\theta)\ \mathrm{d}\theta&= \sum_{m=0}^{\ell}a_{\ell m} \int_0^{\pi} \cos (n\theta) \cos[(\ell -2m)\theta] \ \mathrm{d}{\theta}\\
            &\overset{(1)}{=}\sum_{m=0}^{\ell} a_{\ell m} \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\delta_{\ell-2m,n}+\frac{\pi}{2}\delta_{2m-\ell,n}\right)\\
            &\overset{(2)}{=}\pi\sum_{m=0}^{\ell}a_{\ell m}\delta_{\ell-2m,n}
\end{align}
Finally, the result of this integral is:
\begin{align}
        &\int_0^{\infty} p\ \mathrm{d}{p} \int_0^{\pi} \ \mathrm{d}{\theta} \frac{\cos n \theta}{(p^2 + k^2 - 2pk \cos\theta)^{1/2}} \\[.2cm]
        ={}&\sum_{\ell=2}^{\infty} \frac{2\ell+1}{(\ell+2)(\ell-1)}k \sum_{m=0}^{\ell} \pi a_{\ell m}\delta_{\ell-2m,n}\\[.2cm]
        \overset{(2)}{=}{}&\sum_{\ell =n,\  2|(\ell-n)}^{\infty}\frac{2\ell+1}{(\ell+2)(\ell-1)}\pi k a_{\ell,\frac{\ell-n}{2}},\quad j\mapsto \frac{\ell-n}{2}\\[.2cm]
        ={}&\pi k \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{2(2j+n)+1}{(2j+n+2)(2j+n-1)} a_{2j+n,j}\\[.2cm]
        ={}&\boxed{ \pi k \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{2(2j+n)+1}{(2j+n+2)(2j+n-1)} \frac{(2j-1)!!}{(2j)!!}\frac{(2j+2n-1)!!}{(2j+2n)!!}}
\end{align}
where,

1. $\displaystyle{\int_0^{\pi} \cos mx \cos nx \ \mathrm{d}{x} = \frac{\pi}{2}\delta_{mn},\quad (m,n\in\mathbb{N}^{+})}$
2. $\displaystyle{
   \ell-2m  = -\ell, -\ell+2,-\ell+4, \cdots, \ell-2,\ell}$.

---

**My Question:**

I have try to calculate this series via `Mathematica`, I define
\begin{align}
f(n) &=  \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{2(2j+n)+1}{(2j+n+2)(2j+n-1)} \frac{(2j-1)!!}{(2j)!!}\frac{(2j+2n-1)!!}{(2j+2n)!!}\\[.2cm]
&=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2j+n+2}\frac{(2j-1)!!}{(2j)!!}\frac{(2j+2n-1)!!}{(2j+2n)!!} + \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2j+n-1}\frac{(2j-1)!!}{(2j)!!}\frac{(2j+2n-1)!!}{(2j+2n)!!}
\end{align}
I have found that this series has a very simple form:
\begin{align}
f(2)= \frac{2}{3},\quad f(3) = \frac{3}{8},\quad f(4) = \frac{4}{15},\quad f(5)=\frac{5}{24},\quad f(6)=\frac{6}{35},\quad \cdots
\end{align}
It seems to imply that the original integral result was:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty} p\ \mathrm{d}{p} \int_0^{\pi} \ \mathrm{d}{\theta} \frac{\cos n \theta}{(p^2 + k^2 - 2pk \cos\theta)^{1/2}} \overset{?}{=} \boxed{\color{red}{  \frac{n}{n^2-1}\pi k} }
\end{equation}
The computer tells this result should be correct, but I can't get this result by simplifying the series.

**Is there any way you can calculate this integral result, or can you simplify my series?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integral is $I_n=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\pi f(p,\theta)\cos n\theta\,d\theta\,dp$ with $f(p,\theta)=p(p^2+k^2-2pk\cos\theta)^{-1/2}$.

The idea is to exchange the integrations *after some preparation*: let, say, $$h(p,\theta)=\begin{cases}\hfill 0,\hfill&0\leqslant p\leqslant k\\1+\frac{k}{p}\cos\theta,&\hfill p>k\hfill\end{cases}$$ so that $\int_0^\pi h(p,\theta)\cos n\theta\,d\theta=0$ (we're using $n>1$ here).

Then, if we put $g(p,\theta)=f(p,\theta)-h(p,\theta)$, we get $I_n=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\pi g(p,\theta)\cos n\theta\,d\theta\,dp$.

Now $g(p,\theta)$ is (absolutely) integrable, and $\int_0^\infty g(p,\theta)\,dp$ is *elementary*:
$$\small\int\frac{p\,dp}{\sqrt\triangle}=\sqrt\triangle+kc\log(p-kc+\sqrt\triangle)+\text{const.}\qquad\color{gray}{\left\{\begin{aligned}c&=\cos\theta\\\triangle&=p^2+k^2-2pkc\end{aligned}\right.}$$
implies, for $p>k$,
$$\small\int_0^p g(\bar{p},\theta)\,d\bar{p}=\sqrt\triangle-p+kc\log\frac{p-kc+\sqrt\triangle}{p(1-c)}$$
so that, after taking $p\to\infty$, we get
$$\int_0^\infty g(p,\theta)\,dp=-k\cos\theta\left(1+2\log\left|\sin\frac\theta2\right|\right).$$

Thus, after exchanging the integrations (and using $n>1$ again),
$$I_n=-2k\int_0^\pi\log\left|\sin\frac\theta2\right|\cos\theta\cos n\theta\,d\theta=k(J_{n-1}+J_{n+1}),$$
with
$$J_n=-\int_0^\pi\log\left|\sin\frac\theta2\right|\cos n\theta\,d\theta=\frac\pi{2n}\qquad(n>0)$$ evaluated, say, using
$$-\log\left|2\sin\frac\theta2\right|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos n\theta}n.$$

Comment: This is very nice and moreover elegant.

Comment: Thank for your answer, this is indeed a very concise and powerful solution.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you computed $\int_0^\infty g(p,\theta) dp$?

Comment: @AndrewYuan: Done (with a tiny fix).

Answer (score 3):

Trying to simplify the summation (after the partial fraction decomposition)
$$\frac{(2j-1)!!}{(2j)!!}\frac{(2j+2n-1)!!}{(2j+2n)!!}=\frac 1\pi \,\frac{\Gamma \left(j+\frac{1}{2}\right)\,\, \Gamma
   \left(j+n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (j+1)\,\, \Gamma (j+n+1)}$$
$$f(n)=S_1(n)+S_2(n)$$ where
$$S_1(n)=\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } (n-1)
   \Gamma (n+1)}\,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{2n+1}{2}
   ;\frac{n+1}{2},n+1;1\right)$$
$$S_2(n)=\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }
   (n+2) \Gamma (n+1)}\,\,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n+2}{2},\frac{2n+1}{2};\frac{n+4}{
   2},n+1;1\right)$$
I did not find any way to simplify (inspite of [all of this](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/06/01/04/01/03/) but, as you did, observe
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
n & S_1(n) & S_2(n) & f(n)=S_1(n)+S_2(n) \\
 2 & \frac{14}{9 \pi } & \frac{2}{3}-\frac{14}{9 \pi } &
   \frac{2}{3} \\
 3 & \frac{3}{8}-\frac{2}{5 \pi } & \frac{2}{5 \pi } &
   \frac{3}{8} \\
 4 & \frac{818}{1575 \pi } & \frac{4}{15}-\frac{818}{1575 \pi }
   & \frac{4}{15} \\
 5 & \frac{5}{24}-\frac{50}{189 \pi } & \frac{50}{189 \pi } &
   \frac{5}{24} \\
 6 & \frac{12622}{40425 \pi } & \frac{6}{35}-\frac{12622}{40425
   \pi } & \frac{6}{35} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Nice partial solution; it seems it confirms the answer is $\frac{n}{n^2-1}$.
I got 
$$f(n)=2\int_0^1dt\,(t^{n+1}+t^{n-2})\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma^2(\frac12+n+k)}{\Gamma^2(1+n+k)}t^{2k}$$
I wonder if there is a way to evaluate this sum?

Comment: That's exactly why I'm asking this question. My process of solving this integral may be overcomplicated, I believe there might be a very simple solution to this integral which doesn't require calculating these complicated series, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: @HuanyuShi. I wanted to know where the simple result was coming from. Since we know nom metamorphy's result, it is more than clear than we  must not start with the inner integral which is already an $\,_3F_2\left(.\right)$ hypergeometric function (with restrictions moreover).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I have calculated the results of n=2,3,4...10 via `mathematica`. Their result is as I said in the question, so I'm guessing it is $\frac{n}{n^2-1}\pi k$. So this result is entirely my **guess**, but I have verified some special cases with a computer, and they are all consistent.